# Why does the main thread guarantee the UIView.animate method?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I wonder how the UIView.animate method works.
because just UI method must be used from main thread only?

try it

- UIView.animate method was called without Dispatchqueue.main.async
- so, I check Thread.isMainthread in UIView.animate result -> main

I think that because UIView use @MainActor annotation
But, Is there any counter case where @MainActor doesn't guarantee the main thread?

Questions

1. Why does the main thread guarantee the UIView.animate method?
2. Is my guess correct?

if my guess correct {
2-1. Is there any counter case where @MainActor doesn't guarantee the main thread?
}

Comment: I'd say it call itself the `Dispatchqueue.main.async()` on the first closure, that's why it's working.

Comment: @Larme Do you mean to call `Dispatchqueue.main.async()` by itself?
I don't find descripion on Apple Developer Document, I want a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thread guarantees the UIView.animate method because it manipulates UI elements, which should only be done on the main thread to ensure thread safety and avoid unexpected behavior.

Your guess is partially correct. The @MainActor attribute is used to mark methods that must be executed on the main thread. However, there may be cases where the attribute is not used correctly or where it does not fully guarantee that the method is executed on the main thread. For example, if a method marked with @MainActor calls another method that is not marked as such, or if a method is marked with @MainActor but also includes asynchronous code that is not properly managed, it could result in the method being executed on a background thread. Therefore, it's important to use @MainActor carefully and ensure that all related code is properly managed to avoid potential issues.